# Does ARC support for encrypted SQLlite data base?

Tags: google-chrome, apk, google-chrome-arc

I have SQL lite database in my apk. The database is encrypted. Does arc support an encrypted database ? Or is there any other way I can make sure the data is not compromised. Since it will be multi user environment it is imperative that the data stays protected. Thanks.

Comment: Encryption of a SQLite database can be very effective to protect the user's data against people who are not the user. Encryption of a SQLite database -- whether on ARC or elsewhere -- is useless for protecting data *from the user*, as they can trivially get the decryption key from inside the app.

Comment: It is a pharmaceutical product. So I need the data to be secured at all times. Also the database is at the user's system so there is no retrieving of data from the server. All the content is stored locally. What strategies can I use to ensure my data is secure ?

Comment: "So I need the data to be secured at all times" -- then put it on a server. "All the content is stored locally" -- then by definition, it is insecure. This is the case for every operating system written in human history.